# Why does location.replace() executes while AJAX request is still running?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, replace, location

I have this piece of code:

```
getClients(id);
location.replace('/login/index.html');
```

My `getClients()` function is basically an **asyc** `AJAX` request.
If the clients list is empty, it redirects to another page. Here's the code *inside the ajax request*:

```
....
success: function(data){
    var json2 = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data.result));
    $.cookie('usu', id, {path: '/'});
    if(json2.length < 2 && json2[0].UserClients.length === 0){  
        location.replace('/login/user_config.html');
        return false;
    }
    else{
        ....
```

But somehow, if the clients object is empty, it is executing `location.replace('/login/index.html');` first, and then executing  `location.replace('/login/user_config.html');`
How can I solve that?

Comment: Put `location.replace('/login/index.html');` inside of the success callback. If you require a certain order for things to execute, you need to use callbacks to define the ordering when using async functions, otherwise the order things run will depend on how long it takes for the async method to return. Note that `getClients` doesn't wait for the async to finish; it will return immediately.

Comment: @Carcigenicate that solved the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem using @Carcigenicate  suggestion to use a **callback**.
The result code is like this:

```
getClients(id, location.replace('/login/index.html'));
```

Thak you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As this process is dynamic and you need to wait for AJAX response, so I think you can use a **Loader** and call it before sending request to AJAX also if your condition don't match then in that case hide loader from display.

A short code may help you,

```
beforeSend:function(){
    // init loader here
},
success: function(data){
    var json2 = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data.result));
    $.cookie('usu', id, {path: '/'});
    if(json2.length < 2 && json2[0].UserClients.length === 0){  
        location.replace('/login/user_config.html');
        return false;
    }
    else{
        // stop loader here
```